ignore certain properties in gradle.properties file in local environment
I am trying to upgrade the java version as a part of react native upgrade to 0.74
and would like to ignore certain property in my local environment since the path doesn't exists:
org.gradle.java.home=/Users/username/.sdkman/candidates/java/current

Referring to this doc. https://www.githang.com/gradledoc/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties
but so far not finding any luck.
UPDATE
found a workaround which doesn't involve modifying the gradle.properties file which was to update the jenkinsfile
export JAVA_HOME=/Users/<YOUR_PATH_TO_JAVA>/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims
